# Problems getting index of Iframe playlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I am not using Iframe's api but simply embedding iframe as follows.

```
 <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
    src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PLAYLISTID`}
    frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Is there a way to call the function `player.getPlaylistIndex():Number` without implementing iframe's api?

Comment: I doubt it because of [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)